# Add string to char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, fgets

I have a C array called buf. Here is it's definition:

`char buf[1024];`

Now, my current code takes from `stdin` and uses `fgets()` to set that array, however I wish to use code to set it instead. Right now the line that sets buf looks like this:

`fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);`

Basically, I want to replace stdin, with say... "My String". What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look for `sprintf`, for example here: [Cpp reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/)

Edit:

```
sprintf(buf, "My string with args %d", (long) my_double_variable);
```

Edit 2:

As suggested to avoid overflow (but this one is standard C) you can use [snprintf](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/io/snprintf).

Comment: look at sprintf_s to make it safe and avoid buffer overflow attacks.

Comment: @KLee1: Generally good advice. However, given that the string is going to be supplied inside the code, not a user supplied buffer, a buffer overflow attack seems unlikely.

Comment: Yep that did it! Thanks, will be using _s as well. Thanks guys!

Comment: @KLee1:  I saw nothing in the question to indicate the OP is working in an environment that has "sprintf_s", which does not appear to be in C99.

Comment: +1 for standards and portability, avoiding the `_s` functions.

Comment: Nver use sprintf_s. Its not portable.

Comment: All the _s functions are Microsoft extensions, and almost all of them are pointless duplicates of functionality that was available somewhere else.  sprintf_s is no better than snprintf.  But definitely use snprintf.

Comment: @all Sorry, I meant snprintf.  My bad.

Answer (score 5):

snprintf is only C99 not C89, sprintf_s/strcpy_s are only MSVC, not C89, not C99.

```
char *mystr="come from stdin or file or ...";
char buf[1024];
...
memset(buf,0,sizeof buf);
strncpy(buf,mystr,(sizeof buf)-1);
```

or non array:

```
#define BUFLEN 512
char *mystr="come from stdin or file or ...";
char *buf;
...
char *buf=calloc(1,BUFLEN);
strncpy(buf,mystr,BUFLEN-1);
```

It works on all ANSI C environments.

Answer (score 3):

```
strcpy(buf, "My String");
```

Microsoft's compiler also include a function strcpy_s, which is a "safe" version of strcpy.  It makes sure that you won't overrun `buf`.  In this particular case, that's probably not a problem, but you shoul dknow about.  But, be aware, it's not available with any other compiler, so it can;t be used where portable is needed.

```
 strcpy_s(buf, sizeof(buf), "My String");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many variants, some have been already proposed, some not:

```
...

char input[] = "My String";

strcpy(buf, input);

strncpy(buf, input, sizeof(buf));

sscanf(input, "%s", buf);

sprintf(buf, "%s", input);

memcpy(buf, input, strlen(input));

...
```

most of them are unsure/insecure. What exactly should be taken depends
on **what you really want to** do in your code.

Regards

rbo

Answer (score -1):

Verbose but safe:

```
int copy_size = sizeof( buf ) - 1 < strlen( MyString ) ? sizeof( buf ) - 1 : strlen( MyString );
memset( buf, 0, copy_size + 1 );
memcpy( buf, MyString, copy_size );
```

Comment: this is horrible.  why do  you zero out so much memory just to overwrite it with memcpy?  look at BSD's strlcpy.